# Loopback4 User Signup/Login: How to customize User fields based on example at https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

related to user signup and login

how can the user fields be modified(add and remove fields according to the business needs) based on the documentation as https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html  ?

for example the user in the example already has fields

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "realm": "string",
  "username": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "verificationToken": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "additionalProp1": {}
}
```

but i do not need all of them, and i need other fields too

In the example there are these imports

```
import {
  Credentials,
  MyUserService,
  TokenServiceBindings,
  User,
  UserRepository,
  UserServiceBindings,
} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';
```

which show that the user is somehow predefined in module @loopback/authentication-jwt.
How can i customize the user ?

thank you

Comment: For future cross-reference; This question has also been posted on the Slack channel: https://loopbackio.slack.com/archives/C01177XQN8N/p1611651472072700.

Comment: The question has also been posted on the GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/7072

Comment: I found a blog post which helps: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5709#issuecomment-759154995

It describes there more ways to add Postgres DataSource, including a possibility to change the User fields.

Answer (score 1):

- Here is a link to info about how to customize the User Auth related Component: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/JWT-authentication-extension.html#customization
- An answer from other issue that helps: [#5709 (comment)](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5709#issuecomment-759154995) (It describes there more ways to use a Postgresql DataSource for user signup and login, including a possibility to change the User fields)